# C++ forward properties / members declaration between 2 classes

Tags: c++, class, types, declaration, member

What is the best and **shortest** way to code these classes without compiler error

*"field 'image' has incomplete type Image image;"*

```
struct ImageFrame {
   Image image;
};
struct Image {
   ImageFrame imageFrame;
};
```

I have tried putting

```
struct ImageFrame;
struct Image;
```

before, but error still occurs, even if the order of anything is changed.

**EDIT**: Using reference it works like this:

```
struct ImageFrame;
struct Image;

struct ImageFrame {
    Image* image;
};
struct Image {
    ImageFrame imageFrame;
};
```

Are there any memory issues at "Image* image" I should take care of? (memory leaks if *image not deleted)

Comment: Use references or pointers in the declaration of the member variables.

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. A class cannot contain itself. If you ever manage to do this, our universe will immediately disappear into a massive black hole.

Comment: _"Are there any memory issues at "Image* image" I should take care of?"_ Not more than already are considered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)